# MQTT Subscriber in VB.Net using M2MQTT

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make MQTT subscriber work in VB.NET. I'm using M2MQTT for this purpose. Below is the code.

```
Sub client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(sender As Object, e As 
                                    MqttMsgPublishEventArgs)
    MsgBox(e.Message())
    MsgBox(e.Message)

End Sub
```

Test Code

```
  Dim k As New MqttClient("broker.hivemq.com", 1883, False, New 
                                            X509Certificate)
    MsgBox(k.Settings.Port())

    Dim clientId As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    AddHandler k.MqttMsgPublishReceived, AddressOf client_MqttMsgPublishReceived
    k.Connect(clientId, "test", "test")

    k.Subscribe(New String() {"start"}, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_MOST_ONCE))

    MsgBox(k.IsConnected())
```

So IsConnected() is returning false in this code. What wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 3):

This project may be useful.
It contains all the features of a library M2Mqtt

https://github.com/bassouma21001/MQTTBasic